# Django 1.7 ImageField form validation

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-1.7, django-tests

I'm writing unit tests using Django 1.7 with Python 3.4. The form below validates fine when the `file_data` element is commented out. With the `file_data` included it doesn't validate and the test fails.

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
...

data = {
    'phone_number': '123456',
    'job': Job.objects.latest('id').pk,
}
file_data = {
    'portrait': SimpleUploadedFile(
        content=b'',
        content_type='image/jpeg',
        name='test.jpg',
    )
}
form = PersonForm(data, file_data)
self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

Similar code works fine for `FileField` upload tests elsewhere in my site. Running the code in a shell I get the following in `form.errors`: `'Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.'` I therefore think the problem lies either in the `content` or `content_type` fields. I've tried using an image-as-a-string as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2473445/1280784) to no avail. **[Edit: the image-as-a-string approach was in fact the answer but I must've implemented it badly. The accepted answer is verified as working.]** I couldn't find any clues in the [SimpleUloadedFile source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py).

The form works fine in reality but I want to make sure it's covered by a working test for future maintenance. Ideally I'd like to avoid having to have an actual `test.jpg` file existing because images are in my `.gitignore` file and I don't want to have to start hacking what is currently a very smooth automated deployment.

What input should I give `SimpleUploadedFile` so that it validates correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there any difference of running `Image` lib between your test suit and your working code? Can the `Image` lib process files such as GIF properly? You may need to check the `PIL/pillow` installation as well.

```
SimpleUploadedFile(name='foo.gif', 
                   content=b'GIF87a\x01\x00\x01\x00\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00ccc,\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\x02D\x01\x00')
```

works for me.

The form internally relies on `forms.ImageField` to test image in its `to_python()`, in the way like:

```
import io
from django.utils.image import Image
Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_content)).verify()
```

Any exception from the `verify()` line would result in the error `'Upload a valid image...'`. You could check the image bytes by assigning it to `image_content`:

```
image_content = b'GIF87a\x01\x00\x01\x00\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00ccc,\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\x02D\x01\x00'
```

works for me either.

Also, you could generate image bytes online:

```
import io    
from django.utils.image import Image
fp = io.BytesIO()
Image.new('P', (1,1)).save(fp, 'png')
fp.seek(0)
portrait = SimpleUploadedFile(name=''foo, content=fp.read())
```

Comment: Strangely the first solution worked straight away, but I could swear it was one of the things I tried. I must've had a typo somewhere originally. Thanks.