# Django testing model with ImageField

Tags: python, django, testing, mocking

I need to test the Photo model of my Django application. How can I mock the ImageField with a test image file?

**tests.py**

```
class PhotoTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_add_photo(self):
        newPhoto = Photo()
        newPhoto.image = # ??????
        newPhoto.save()
        self.assertEqual(Photo.objects.count(), 1)
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141786/django-1-7-imagefield-form-validation) may have some relevant insight.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't figure to use it to solve my problem :(

Answer (score 115, accepted):

For future users, I've solved the problem.
You can mock an [`ImageField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) with a [`SimpleUploadedFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form) instance.

**test.py**

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

newPhoto.image = SimpleUploadedFile(name='test_image.jpg', content=open(image_path, 'rb').read(), content_type='image/jpeg')
```

Comment: perfect, should be the accepted answer. Works in 1.10, thanks!

Comment: @Norak Through some experimentation, I found that `name` is the filename you want to use for the image you read in and the `image_path` is the path of your image. For example `/path/to/image.jpg`.

Comment: setting content_type is optional.

Comment: This way works but every time I run test the  new image file is created in /media directory.

Comment: Can you set a binary for the content ? `content=b"some content"` so that you don't have to have an actual image just for the tests ?

Answer (score 31):

You can use a temporary file, using [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html). So you don't need a real file to do your tests.

```
import tempfile

image = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".jpg").name
```

If you prefer to do manual clean-up, use `tempfile.mkstemp()` instead.

Answer (score 26):

Tell the mock library to create a mock object based on Django's File class

```
import mock
from django.core.files import File

file_mock = mock.MagicMock(spec=File, name='FileMock')
```

and then use in your tests

```
newPhoto.image = file_mock
```

Comment: then you can open any arbitary image from any location `newPhoto.image = open(/path/to/foo.jpg)`

Comment: but always if I use mock module?

Comment: Mock is now a standard python library from Python>=3.3 so don't see this third-party library as something weird in Python.

Comment: @ChillarAnand I use your example, but I have an error - `TypeError: 'MagicMock' does not support the buffer interface`

Answer (score 25):

If you don't want to create an actual file in the filesystem, you can use this 37-byte GIF instead, small enough to a be a bytes literal in your code:

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

small_gif = (
    b'\x47\x49\x46\x38\x39\x61\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x21\xf9\x04'
    b'\x01\x0a\x00\x01\x00\x2c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02'
    b'\x02\x4c\x01\x00\x3b'
)
uploaded = SimpleUploadedFile('small.gif', small_gif, content_type='image/gif')
```

Comment: This yields a single white pixel. I found another gif, even smaller (only 35 bytes), which yields a single black pixel. If anyone is interested, it is: `b'\x47\x49\x46\x38\x39\x61\x01\x00\x01\x00\x80\x00\x00\x05\x04\x04\x00\x00\x00\x2c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\x02\x44\x01\x00\x3b'`

Answer (score 13):

Solution:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
# in python 3: from io import StringIO
from PIL import Image
from django.core.files.base import File
```

And create a static method in your TestCase class:

```
@staticmethod
def get_image_file(name='test.png', ext='png', size=(50, 50), color=(256, 0, 0)):
    file_obj = StringIO()
    image = Image.new("RGB", size=size, color=color)
    image.save(file_obj, ext)
    file_obj.seek(0)
    return File(file_obj, name=name)
```

Example:

```
instance = YourModel(name=value, image=self.get_image_file())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just note that for python 3:
`from io import StringIO`

Comment: For Python 3 I think `from io import BytesIO` instead of `StringIO`

Answer (score 3):

You can do a few additional things to (1) avoid having to keep a dedicated test image around, and (2) ensure that all test files created during testing are deleted right after:

```py
import shutil
import tempfile

from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings

MEDIA_ROOT = tempfile.mkdtemp()

@override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT=MEDIA_ROOT)
class MyTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        shutil.rmtree(MEDIA_ROOT, ignore_errors=True)  # delete the temp dir
        super().tearDownClass()

    def test(self):
        img = SimpleUploadedFile('test.jpg', b'whatevercontentsyouwant')
        # ^-- this will be saved in MEDIA_ROOT
        # do whatever ...
```

Answer (score 2):

For someone to try upload-image test with python 3.xx

I fix little with Maxim Panfilov's excellent answer to make more dummy image with independent name.

```py
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from django.core.files.base import File

#in your TestCase class:
class TestClass(TestCase):
    @staticmethod
    def get_image_file(name, ext='png', size=(50, 50), color=(256, 0, 0)):
        file_obj = BytesIO()
        image = Image.new("RGBA", size=size, color=color)
        image.save(file_obj, ext)
        file_obj.seek(0)
        return File(file_obj, name=name)

    def test_upload_image(self):
        c= APIClient()
        image1 = self.get_image('image.png')
        image2 = self.get_image('image2.png')
        data = 
            { 
                "image1": iamge1,
                "image2": image2,
            }
        response = c.post('/api_address/', data ) 
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach how to test model with no intention to pass any useful data:

```
from django.core.files import File
SomeModel.objects.create(image=File(file=b""))
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to offer another testing option, which does not require the presence of a file on the server or local machine. Perhaps it will seem interesting to someone and will be useful in the future.

```
from .models import Photo
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

import requests # pip install requests
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
    
class PhotoTestCase(TestCase):
    
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        url = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" # for example
        response = requests.get(url)
        im = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
        im_bytes = BytesIO()
        im.save(fp=im_bytes, format="PNG", quality=100)
        content = im_bytes.getvalue()
        newPhoto = Photo()
        newPhoto.image = SimpleUploadedFile(
            name='test_image.png',
            content=content,
            content_type='image/jpeg')
        newPhoto.save()

    def test_add_photo(self):
        photo_object = Photo.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(Photo.objects.count(), 1)
        photo_object.image.delete() # It is mandatory that the file is not saved on the HDD (SSD)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Factory Boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to generate your test data, that library handles this situation with an [ImageField factory](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/orms.html#factory.django.ImageField).

Here is a complete example. I'm assuming that all of these files are in the same Django app.

models.py example:

```
from django.db import models


class YourModel(models.Model):
    
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="files/")
```

factories.py example:

```
import factory
from . import models


class YourModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    
    class Meta:
        model = models.YourModel
 
    image = factory.Django.ImageField()
```

tests.py example:

```
from django import test    
from . import factories


class YourModelTests(test.TestCase):
    
    def test_image_model(self):
        yourmodel = factories.YourModelFactory()
        self.assertIsNotNone(yourmodel.image)
```