# Can't upload image file while testing Django

Tags: django, unit-testing, python-3.x

I am developing API using Django REST Framework. 
I have a Django model that has `models.ImageField` and it works just fine.
But when I want to unittest creating model object, I get error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

My code:

```
class PlacesTest(APITestCase):

    . . .

    def test_create_place_full(self):
        . . .
        image = SimpleUploadedFile(name='test.jpg',
                                   content=open('test.png', 'rb').read(),
                                   content_type='image/jpeg')

        request = self.factory.post(reverse('place-list'),
                                    {'name': 'test_place_1',
                                     'picture': image,  
                                     })
```

I have tried passing `string` with path to image, and I've tried methods from [Django testing model with ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298821/django-testing-model-with-imagefield) to do tests, but no success.

What type should I pass to Django REST framework when adding image: file object or string with path?

How can I add real file to my tests?

Answer (score 3):

Found solution for my problem if someone is interested:

all I needed was specifying `format='multipart'` in request arguments:

```
request = self.factory.post(reverse('place-list'),
                                {'name': 'test_place_1',
                                 'picture': self.image},
                                format='multipart')
```

in my project was:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json'
}
```

so no image could be added to POST request.