# How to write test for Django image url

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, django-testing

I'm writing my first test as a Django developer.
How do I write a test for the image property of this model shown below

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    engineer = models.ForeignKey(Engineer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tech_used = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default="project.png")
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    repo_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    live_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    make_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def image_url(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ""
        return url

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created"]
```

I have tried to conjure some patches from here and there although I don't fully understand what my test.py code I just thought to include it to my question to show my efforts

```py
class TestModels(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        new_image = BytesIO()
        self.image = Project.objects.create(
            image=ImageFile(new_image)
        )

    def test_image_url(self):

        self.assertEquals(self.image.image_url, '')
```

Please a help on the above question and an explanation of whatever code given as help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26307916/7100120), one possible way is:

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

from django.test import TestCase
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Engineer, Project


class ProjectImageUploadTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.engineer = Engineer.objects.create(name='Engineer')
        self.project = {
                'engineer': self.engineer,
                'name': 'Test project',
                'tech_used': 'Test tech',
                'updated': timezone.now(),
                'created': timezone.now(),
                'image': None,
                'description': 'Test description',
                'repo_url': 'https://www.repo.example.com',
                'live_url': 'https://www.live.example.com',
                'make_public': False
            }
        self.obj = Project.objects.create(**self.project)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.obj.image.delete()

    def test_upload_image(self):
        img_url = r'X:\Path\to\your\image.png'
        self.obj.image=  SimpleUploadedFile(
            name='test_image.jpg', 
            content=open(img_url, 'rb').read(), 
            content_type='image/png')
        self.obj.save()
        self.obj.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertNotEqual(self.obj.image, None)
```

I would like to complement saying that is also possible to implement the test using Python's [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html).

Comment: Thanks but I still get an error, more importantly I just want to test ONLY the image field, is that possible?

Comment: I did test only the image field `self.assertNotEqual(self.obj.image, None)`. Your field is inside the project object, so we need to create one to test the upload. Although you could reduce the number of fields for only the required ones.

Comment: Can't help if you do not give details of the mentioned error.

Comment: Thanks your solution worked but with a few modification though, I am new to writing test so the 'presumed' errors I saw was to be expected, thanks again.

Comment: i think the question was asking to test for the value of a image field url attribute, not the nullidity

Answer (score 0):

To test for the url value of the image field of a model. use the code below, the code was written in pytest but the idea can be refactor and implemented in unittest tests.

#### models.py

```py
...
class Project(models.Model):
    ... # other fields ignore for brevity
    image = models.ImageField(default="project.png")
```

#### tests.py

```py
import pytest
from django.conf import settings
# ensure that you have set your MEDIA_URL variable in your project settings, example; MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

from myapp.models import Project

IMAGE_FILE = "test_file.png"

@pytest.fixture
def project_one():
    return Project.objects.create(
        # other attribute filled in
        image = IMAGE_FILE,
        )

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_project_image_url(project_one):
    assert project_one.image.url = f"{settings.MEDIA_URL}{IMAGE_FILE}"
```