# Testing a form on Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to run a test on a form. It keeps returning invalid. Other forms work fine though.

**The form in forms.py:**

```
class SongForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta():
    model = Song
    fields = ('title', 'type', 'audio_file', 'description', 'written_by', 'song_text')
```

**The model the form comes from in models.py:**

```
class Song(models.Model):
title          = models.CharField(max_length=120)
SONG_TYPES     = (
    ('KI', 'Kiirtan'),
    ('PS', 'Prabhat Samgiita'),
    ('BH', 'Bhajan'),
)
type              = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=SONG_TYPES)
capo              = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, validators=[MaxValueValidator(12)])
description       = models.TextField(blank=True)
uploader          = models.ForeignKey('Profile', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
written_by        = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)      
song_text         = models.TextField(blank=True)
audio_file        = models.FileField(upload_to='songs/')
upload_date       = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
edit_date         = models.DateField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
chords            = models.ManyToManyField('Chord', related_name='chords', through='ChordIndex')
```

**The test in tests/test_forms.py:**

```
def test_Song_form_is_valid(self):
    the_data = {
      'title': 'a song',
      'type': 'KI',
      'description': '',
      'audio_file': '103_VASANTA_AJ_JAGALO_04Tsyry.mp3'
      'written_by': '',
      'song_text': '',
    }
    form = SongForm(data=the_data)
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

The form works correctly in the web app with a POST method. I even tried copying the values from a valid POST on the test and it still failed!

I've been stuck with this for a while... Any clues?

Comment: My problem was testing a form with a FileField. This post solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473392/unit-testing-a-django-form-with-a-filefield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print the values of `form.errors`, from the looks of the code above you forgot to add `audio_file`, you can fix this by adding `null=True, blank=True` on the field `audio_file` in your models.

Comment: Good catch. I edited the question with audio_file included. Still same result.

Comment: You are correct! That is the field that is giving me problems. Setting it to null=True, blank=True does solve the problem. Except that I need this field to be mandatory. But now at least I know what is going on. More later once I solve it